# What is invalid about my form with jquery .valid() failing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate

I have a simple form and I validate it, but then I check to see if it's valid and it is always invalid. How can I check to see what is invalid about my form? If I swap out the razor code with html for the text box it seems to work. I posted the rendered razor code below.

Here is my form -

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "MyForm", name = "MyForm" }))
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SearchQuery, new { @class = "form-control", name = "FullAddress", id = "FullAddress" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SearchQuery, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
    }
```

And here is my script. It displays a alert box every time I hit the submit button and this line is checked

```
if (!$('#MyForm').valid()) {
            alert('Invalid Form!');



$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('#MyForm').exists()) {

        // Enable jQuery Validation for the form
        //$("#MyForm").validate({ onkeyup: false, onfocusout: false });
        $("#MyForm").validate();



    var errors = validator.errors(); //get the error elements, the actual labels
    var errors1 = validator.invalidElements();

        // Add validation rules to the FullAddress field
        $("#FullAddress").rules("add", {
            fulladdress: true,
            required: true,
            messages: {
                fulladdress: "Google cannot locate this address."
            }
        });

        // This function will be executed when the form is submitted
        function FormSubmit() {
            $.submitForm = true;
            if (!$('#MyForm').valid()) {
                alert('Invalid Form!');

                return false;
            } else {
                if ($("#FullAddress").data("IsChecking") == true) {
                    $("#FullAddress").data("SubmitForm", true);
                    return false;
                }

                alert('Form Valid!  Submit!');
                // return true;   // Uncomment to submit the form.
                return false;     // Supress the form submission for test purpose.

            }
        }

        // Attach the FormSubmit function to the Submit button
        if ($('#Submit').exists()) {
            $("#Submit").click(FormSubmit);
        }

        // Execute the ForumSubmit function when the form is submitted
        $('#MyForm').submit(FormSubmit);
    }
});

// Create a jQuery exists method
jQuery.fn.exists = function () { return jQuery(this).length > 0; }


function LocationValidator(value, element, paras) {
  ///do stuff here
}

$.validator.addMethod("location", LocationValidator);

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addBool("location");

$.validator.setDefaults({
    onkeyup: false,
    onfocusout: false
});
```

The invalid part of my form is coming from the searchquery textbox. If I change the html to the line below the form passes as valid.

```
<input type="text" id="SearchQuery" name="SearchQuery"  class="form-control"/>
```

Here is what the rendered razor code looks like that is failing my form validation check

```
<input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-location="The location cannot be determined" data-val-required="The Location field is required." id="SearchQuery" name="SearchQuery" type="text" value="" />
```

Comment: The problem is that we have no idea what the `.valid()` function does.

Comment: .valid is a build in jquery method. http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/

Comment: Nope, `valid()` is built in a plugin called jqueryvalidation (link you gave). Not in jQuery.

Comment: Could you post the rendered HTML code, instead of this... preprocessor (?) code?

Comment: yes I see that my searchquery text box is invalid and that's why my form keeps coming up as invalid. If I change my html to standard html tags it passes. I'll post the rendered html for the text box.

Comment: `.valid()` is a [**method** built into the jQuery Validate plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/), not part of jQuery.  Are you including this plugin?

Comment: As stated in the docs, you cannot use `.valid()` without first initializing the plugin with `.validate()`.  However, with ASP, you may be already using `unobtrusive-validate` plugin.  If so, that is already calling the `.validate()` initialization method.

Comment: yes I am using the unobtrusive-validate plugin. So should I not being calling .validate() because it is already validating it? I tried commenting out the validate statement to validate my form but it had no affect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `errorList` property of the validator object returned by the `validate()`:

```
var validator = $("#MyForm").validate(),
    errors = validator.errorList;
```

The property is an array of objects, where each object contains the error message and the HTML element.

Comment: when I check this it's empty. But when I check if !$('#SearchQuery').valid() it is invalid. I swapped out the razor code for html and it passed. I displayed the rendered razor code at the bottom of my post.

Comment: It only validates when you write it yourself because you haven't added any of the data attributes required by JQueryValidation ...